# Commutative algebra text that solely contains 200+ exercises

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, commutative-algebra, book-recommendation

I am looking for a textbook that I came across awhile ago that I have been unable to find for the last week or so of periodic searching.

The textbook had nothing other than, from memory 247 exercises in it. It was either strictly a commutative algebra text, or it was commutative algebra and algebraic geometry.

Does anyone know this text?

Comment: If anyone knows any book like this for other subjects, I would be interested to look, in that case out of curiosity.

Comment: Introduction to commutative algebra by Atiyah and Macdonald is a book with a lot of exercises. But I'm not sure if its the one you meant. It has very little theory.

Comment: @Rise That's a great book and does have a very large exercise ratio, but wasn't the one I meant, thanks though!

Comment: Any further hints?

Comment: @vonbrand That's all I remember unfortunately. I remember scrolling through it online and seeing that it was only exercises and thinking that it was interesting. Then I kept thinking back to it more and more, weird as that sounds.